# Is there way to get google maps polygon co-ordinates value in string format

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is how I am drawing polygon. And I want it get the polygon area as drawn and mark the properties on the map in next page that lies under the drawn polygon area and also draw the polygon on it.I am getting the co-ordinates of the polygon but it is difficult to send the co-ordinates on the url to next page.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [ 'polygon']
          },
          markerOptions: {icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'},
        polygonOptions: {
        editable: true
      }
        });

   google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {

   $.each(event.overlay.getPath().getArray(), function(key, latlng){
            var lat = latlng.lat();
            var lon = latlng.lng();
            console.log(lat, lon); 
            console.log(latlng); //do something with the coordinates
           lats.push({lat:lat,lon:lon});

        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lon)};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {

             var t = results[0].formatted_address.split(',');
             var country = t[t.length-1];
             var state = t[t.length-2];
             locations.push({'state':state,country:country});
           //  console.log(locations);
           //  console.log(lats);
              // locations.push({'state:'lat,lon});
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest using encoded paths in order to send a polygon as a string parameter in the URL of the next page. Maps JavaScript API has geometry library that allows encode and decode array of LatLng into string:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/geometry#encoding

You can use something like

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    var encodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(event.overlay.getPath());
    window.open(m_url + "?path="+encodedPath, "restore polygon"); 
});
```

in page with drawing manager and restore array of LatLng on the next page as

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let encodedPath = params.get("path");

if (encodedPath) {
    var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);

    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: path,
        map: map
    });
}
```

**Proof of concept**

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [ 'polygon']
      },
      markerOptions: {
          icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'},
      polygonOptions: {
          editable: true
      },
      map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
      var encodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(event.overlay.getPath());
      console.log(encodedPath);
      window.open("http://output.jsbin.com/hicomid?path="+encodedPath, "restore polygon"); 
  });


}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=drawing,geometry&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

You can also check this example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/tpvoL426/

I hope this helps!